# Use OpenVPN on TCP 443 without it interfering with my web server

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, tcp, https

I have a VPS running Debian with a LAMP install. It doesn't get much use so I'd like to install OpenVPN to use as my own personal VPN. However, I want to use TCP port 443 (to avoid firewalls).

How can I configure my server so the VPN won't interfere with SSL traffic to the web server on the same machine? Or will there even be a conflict?

I was planning on using [OpenVPN road warrior installer](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) to install OpenVPN.

Comment: @garethTheRed Your comment is misleading and wrong. You can't have two services listening on the same port, but you can have a service that listens on that port and dispatches connections based on the protocol.

Comment: @Gilles, in theory, you can have two services listening on the same port (for instance by running `sh -c 'telnetd & courier-imap'`via inetd) though that wouldn't be very useful as half the clients would get an IMAP server, half of them a telnet server and couldn't decide which to get.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sslh` - Applicative protocol multiplexer 
http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml "Hence sslh acts as a protocol demultiplexer, or a switchboard. Its name comes from its original function to serve SSH and HTTPS on the same port."

(1st hit on google)